# Entity Framework Cannot insert the value NULL into column Identity Specification set to No

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im using Entity Framework code first and have recently created a new Repo model/table called ImportantCases.

I have set up the configuration and model just like every other however when i get to this line in my code:

```
public int CreateImportantCase(ImportantCase newImportantCase)
        {
            _context.ImportantCases.Add(newImportantCase);

            _context.SaveChanges(); // <--- here

            return newImportantCase.ImportantId;
        }
```

I am getting this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ImportantId', table
>   'MyDatabase.dbo.ImportantCases'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been terminated.

My model/configuration look like this:

**Model**

```
public class ImportantCase
{
    public int ImportantId { get; set; }
    public int EvpId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set;}
}
```

**EF Configuration**

```
class ImportantCaseConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ImportantCase>
    {
        public ImportantCaseConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.ImportantId);
        }
    }
```

Prior to calling the create method I am setting up the new `ImportantCase` via the Post method from the view using a view model and model binding:

```
if (imp != null ) // already a record, so update
                {
                    imp.Comment = modifiedExceptionPersonViewModel.Comment;
                    imp.CategoryId = int.Parse(modifiedExceptionPersonViewModel.SelectedCategory);
                    _service.UpdateImportantCase(imp); 
                }
                if (imp == null) //no record so create
                {
                    ImportantCase newImportantCase = new ImportantCase();
                    newImportantCase.Comment = modifiedExceptionPersonViewModel.Comment;
                    newImportantCase.CategoryId = int.Parse(modifiedExceptionPersonViewModel.SelectedCategory);
                    newImportantCase.EvpId = modifiedExceptionPersonViewModel.EvpId;
                    _service.CreateImportantCase(newImportantCase);
                }
```

I've inspected the `newImportantCase` object just before the `SaveChanges` and it looks as I would expect, with the `ImportantId` set to '0', usually EF will just create the ID once the write has completed.

One thing I have noticed however is the Identity Specification is set to `No` when I view the Design of that table, all the other tables that EF has created are set to `Yes`, what have I done differently?

**note**

`EvpId` is the Id of the viewmodel which is being returned from the view, I've just rolled the category and comment properties into this viewmodel in order to deal with them separately in the controller.

**edit**

I have just realised that I stupidly set the `ImportantId` to a string when I ran initially `update-database` but then added a new migration to rectify this later on, not realising EF does not retrospectively sort out the identity specification, is there a way around this?

Comment: To set Identity Specification  you can do this `[Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ImportantId { get; set; }`

Comment: @Eldho What will happen if I delete that table and run update-database again now that I have ImportantId set correctly as an int, will that sort it?

Comment: I think you could update your `ImportantCase` model as specified in the above comment and try a update-database or else you could delete the table and run again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the following to rectify this issue:

1.) Delete the problematic table through management studio.

2.) Make sure the model is amended to have the actual Id (the thing you want as the Identity Specification set to Yes for)

3.) Through the Package Manager Console create a new migration, something like:

```
add-migration "Set ImportantId as Identity Specification"
```

4.) If nothings changed you will see an empty `Up()` and `Down()` method

5.) Modify these with the contents of the migration that initially introduced this table but make sure you set the Id to an int this time, so this:

```
public partial class addedimportantcasetable : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.ImportantCases",
                c => new
                    {
                        ImportantId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        EvpId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Comment = c.String(),
                        CategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ImportantId);                
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.ImportantCases");
        }
    }
```

Is copied into the new migration, but slightly altered to this:

```
public partial class SetImportantIdasIdentitySpecification : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
               "dbo.ImportantCases",
               c => new
               {
                   ImportantId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                   EvpId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                   Comment = c.String(),
                   CategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false),
               })
               .PrimaryKey(t => t.ImportantId);
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.ImportantCases");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dropping the whole database and letting EF recreate it (I'm using code first) solved this problem for me, since I was still in development phase, I let the DB drop. I guess this would also work.

Answer (score 0):

In model ImportantCase change int to int?

```
public class ImportantCase {
public int? ImportantId { get; set; }
public int EvpId { get; set; }
public string Comment { get; set; }
public int CategoryId { get; set;} }
```